# Is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$ true?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

So with the question being true or not:

$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$

I found that it is not true because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ for the $y$ coordinates. Is this true? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not true. It is not a subset strictly speaking. But both sets are isomorphic in a very obvious way, so you can actually identify both sets (by permuting the coordinates) and then write a subset by abuse of notation (as $A\subseteq A$).

Comment: Hi. Can you explain the last part without using "isomorphism" and "permuting", thanks.

Comment: Also, do you mind showing the visual difference between the two Cartesian products? Thanks.

Comment: It is more or less common practice to identify some object with an isomorphic copy of the object, especially if the isomorphism is particularly easy, canonical or well known (although sometimes you have to be a bit careful with this). In this case there is an easy isomorphism (bijection of sets) sending $(n,x)\mapsto (x,n)$. The inverse is given by sending $(x,n)\mapsto (n,x)$.

Comment: If you represent cartesian products the usual way (first set as $x$ axis, second as $y$ axis) then the first product looks like countably many vertical lines (copies of $\mathbb{R}$), one on each integer along the $x$ axis. Similarly, the second product looks like horizontal lines.

Comment: Okay, that make sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, because the statement $$\forall a\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R: a\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z$$ (which is the definition of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$) is not true.

The statement can be proven to not be true because we can see that $$\exists a\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R:a\notin\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z $$
(the negation of the above statement) is true, and it can be proven by taking $a=(0,\frac12)$.